# React: How to traverse through all children nodes in the tree view structure?

Tags: reactjs, treeview

I am working with [react-expandable-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-expandable-treeview) structure for displaying a family tree data. With the following code, I am traversing through the `items` object with family tree data, storing it into `const data` and then recursively passing into TreeView like it is indicated in documentation of react-expandable-treeview:

```
   const items = props.item;
   var x = 0;

   const data = [{
     id: x,
     label: items.first_name, // parent #1
     children: items.children.map( (child, idx) => {
         id: x= ++idx,
         label: child.first_name, // child of parent #1
          children: child.children.map( (child_child) => ({
           id: x = ++idx,
           label: child_child.first_name,
           children: child_child.children
              ? child_child.children.map( (child_child_child) => ({
                  id: x = ++idx,
                  label: child_child_child.first_name,
                  children: child_child_child.children
              }))
              : null
       }))
      }))
     }]
```

However, with the algorithm above, I was able to only get the root node, its children, and two more generations of the family. [This is a screenshot of how the structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAfn7.png), it shows the amount of the nodes and their relationships correctly, but their indexes and first names are not displayed correctly.

I can't figure out how to perform the last mapping function, so that

```
id: x = ++idx,
label: the_rest_of_children.first_name,
children: the_rest_of_children.children
```

worked for the rest of children and expanded all nodes children until the very last node. How can I fix my code to get the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

Use [recursion](https://javascript.info/recursion)

```js
let index = 0
function visit(node) {
  return {
    label: node.first_name,
    id: index++,
    // pass `visit` function as an argument
    children: node.children.map(visit) 
  }
}

const data = visit(props.items)
```

Recursion isn't the only way to traverse tree-like structures. If your tree is extremely complex, it'd be safer to implement [iterative traversal algorithm](http://nmamano.com/blog/iterativetreetraversal/iterativetreetraversal.html):

> If the recursive implementation is so simple, why bother with an iterative one? Of course, to avoid stack overflow. Most runtime engines/compilers set a limit on how many nested calls a program can make. If the height of the tree is larger than this limit, the program will crash with a stack overflow error. ...

But those cases aren't common in web development.